# Php, excel download

Tags: excel, download, content-type, content-disposition

```
 # Excel File 
 $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."XXX.txt";
 $fp = fopen( $filename, "w" );
 fwrite( $fp, $content);
 fclose( $fp );
 chmod($filename, 0755);

 header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel;" );
 header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=XXX.xls" );
 header( "Content-Description: PHP4 Generated Data" );
```

But,
If I push "Excel Download" button, excel file is not opened. 
Just embed browser with simple table opened not excel file.
Someone said conflict in header maybe happened. 
What shall I do? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What happens after you start a download is beyond your script control; it's defined by the browser. You can't force the user to open the file. If your script works properly the file should be downloaded.

If you are saying your problem is that the file shows as a simple HTML table or tabulated text instead of an Excel file, you should know Excel files follow a proprietary structure.